# Relationship between the magnetic dipole of the electron and the polarisation of its radiation

Tags: magnetic-fields, electrons, polarization, photon-emission, hall-effect

When passing through a magnetic field, electrons are deflected sideways. This is the basis of the Lorentz force and all Hall effects. If this is done on a larger scale in particle accelerators or, in the most pronounced case, in the free-electron laser, one sees that the emitted photons are polarized.

How does the theory explain the phenomenon of polarised emission of photons from aligned by their magnetic dipole electrons?

Comment: *How does the theory explain...* What are you looking for? Some long, complicated QED calculation? Or some hand-waving explanation?

Comment: @G.Smith A calculation is based on a theory. A theory is based on phenomena. Exist a theory how (and not that) polarized radiation occurs? Such explanation should be in words probably.

Comment: Emission of electromagnetic radiation has more to do with the electric field and the direction of acceleration

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about the polarization of [synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation), which can be described to high accuracy using only classical electromagnetism. The polarization is due to the geometry of the charged particles' trajectories and has nothing to do with the electron's magnetic moment. Compare to the freshman-physics calculation of [Brewster's angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle), where strong plane polarization appears because the electric field can't be parallel to the reflected ray's direction of motion.  If the Wikipedia page on synchrotron radiation isn't adequate for your purposes, I'm pretty sure it's the subject of a chapter in Jackson.

At a polarized-electron accelerator, like the one at [JLab](http://jlab.org), the electron polarization precesses as the beam is transported through the machine.  The amount of precession depends on the strength of the steering magnets but also on the beam energy when it interacts with those steering magnets. The beam is "born" polarized and can be delivered to an experiment with the polarization pointing in any direction on the sphere. Computing this polarization transport is something that the engineers teach the graduate students to do as part of making sure the polarization is what the experiments need.